# Rendering partial view or action in asp.net c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following model:

```
public partial class CityMaster
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string cityname { get; set; }
}

public partial class CityJourny
{
    public int journyId { get; set; }
    public int fromCity { get; set; } //foreign key from citymaster
    public int ToCity { get; set; } //foreign key from citymaster
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string distance { get; set; }
}

//View model
public partial class VMCity
{
    public CityMaster cm { get; set; }
    public List<CityJourny> cj { get; set; }
}
```

cityview.cshtml:

```
@model APIModels.UserModel.VMCity

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View1";
}

<h2>View1</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>VMCity</legend>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.cm.cityname)

    @* hear I would like to display list of city from city  *@
    @Html.Partial("Partial1",new APIModels.UserModel.VMCity());
</fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

What should I write in my controller action to display data for city and list of city distance with details (we provide bus service from one city to other city)

Comment: `@Html.Partial("Action", "Controller",new APIModels.UserModel.VMCity());`

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad For example we have list of cities like city a,b,c,d We provide bus from city a to city b and city d so when city a is selected it will display city details and list of city for which service is provided

Comment: @Yuliam Chandra in partial view I would like to display 
model APIModels.UserModel.VMCity I will display list of city data

Comment: @sunny-kachwala, if your `Partial1.cshtml` accepts `@model List<APIModels.UserModel.VMJourny>`, then you need to use partial as follow `@Html.Partial("Partial1", Model.cj)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call new on your view model, as that would cause a new empty Model to be used.

You should rather use

`@Html.Partial("Partial1", @Model.APIModels.UserModel.{Name of your collection containing the cities});`

Or if the partial is just displaying one city you need to iterate the list of cities inside your city view

`@foreach (var city in YOUR_CITY_COLLECTION_HERE)
{
    @Html.Partial("Partial1", city);
}`